# Querying the logger through splunk based on a particular value condition

Tags: indexing, splunk, splunk-query

I need to query the logger through splunk, for a particular statement based on a value inside that statement which is > some value. Can someone please help me with below questions ?

1. I tried below index to find out all the occurrences having **"Batch completed in xx (where xx is the value which must be > some specified value )"**. But the results are zero even though there are occurrences satisfying the condition, in the log file.

   ```
   index="My_App_ID"  APP-NAME makeresults | eval _raw="Batch completed in 23" | rex field=_raw "Batch completed in (?<compltd_time>.\d+)" | where compltd_time > 10
   ```
2. I need to write an index which could fetch me out all the occurrences whose value of 100/23 is > (some-value say 10) for the below log statement

   ```
   Batch completed in 23 seconds for 100 UUIDS
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Let me begin by clarifying some terminology.  Splunk does not query loggers.  Loggers send data to Splunk where they are queried.  Data sent to Splunk is stored in indexes.  One searches an index using a "query" or "search", not an "index".

1)  This question is a bit of a jumble.  Also, the formatter ate the regex string so I have to guess about what's in the `rex` command.  The following query works for me.

```
makeresults | eval _raw="Batch completed in 23" 
| rex "Batch completed in (?<compltd_time>\d+)" 
| where compltd_time > 10
```

When your testing is complete, change the query to `index="My_App_ID" APP-NAME | rex field=_raw "Batch completed in (?<compltd_time>\d+)" | where compltd_time > 10`.

2) This is similar to the first answer.  Use `rex` to extract the two numbers from the log then divide them using `eval`.

```
index="My_App_ID" APP-NAME 
| rex "Batch completed in (?<compltd_time>\d+) seconds for (?<UUIDS>\d+)" 
| eval ratio=UUIDS/compltd_time | where ratio > 10
```

Comment: Hello @RichG. Thank you for the response. I have tried below command but still no results are found even though we have entry in the log
makeresults | eval _raw="Batch completed in 23" 
| rex "Batch completed in (?<compltd_time>.\d+)" 
| where compltd_time > 10

Comment: If you change `.\d+` to `\d+` then the query will work.